# Export a csv for each nested dataframe in a dataframe

Tags: r, csv, kable

I have a dataframe with nested datraframes for every year. I'm trying to export each nested dataframe in the result column as a csv.

It looks like this:

```
MWU_Results
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    YEAR    data.oratios data.kfmaratios result           
   <dbl> <list<df[,16]>> <list<df[,16]>> <list>           
 1  2008        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 2  2009        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 3  2010        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 4  2011        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 5  2012        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 6  2013        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 7  2014        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 8  2015        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
 9  2016        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
10  2017        [8 × 16]      [127 × 16] <tibble [15 × 3]>
```

I would like each csv to include the year in its name.

I've tried the following but both give me errors.

```
temp <- MWU_Results %>% map2(.$result, .$YEAR, ~ write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))

temp <- MWU_Results %>% by_row(~write.csv(.$result, file = .$YEAR))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
purrr::map2(MWU_Results$results, MWU_Results$Year, 
                   ~write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

Or similar with `Map` in base R

```
Map(function(x, y) write.csv(x, file = paste0(y, ".csv")), 
                   MWU_Results$result, MWU_Results$Year)
```

---

When you use pipe operator, the LHS of the pipe is the first input to the next function so `MWU_Results` goes as first input to `map2` in your attempt. This is the default behaviour. You can stop this behaviour by using `{}` around it. So the following should work with pipes.

```
MWU_Results %>% {map2(.$result, .$YEAR, ~ write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. How would I print each table using kableExtra in an RMarkdown document?

Comment: @gm007 Sorry, I haven't really used `kableExtra` so I am not sure how to do it. Maybe you can ask a new question for it and keep this question limited to writing csv.